# is zero operator a compact operator?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Is the zero operator defined on any Banach space X is compact ?
I think this is trivial, because for any bounded set B in X the image set {0} has compact closure as it is finite. Can we generalize this to any general topological space ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that it's trivially a compact operator. However, I'm not sure what you mean by a compact operator on a general topological space. What does it mean for an operator on a general topological space to be e.g. linear? We can't even define boundedness (in the typical sense) in a general topological space. We typically define compact operators between Banach spaces, and this can be generalized to other types of topological vector spaces (Frechet spaces, for example), but certainly not a general topological space.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, but what do you mean by boundedness in typical sense ?

Comment: When we say bounded in a normed space, we mean that it's contained in some ball $\{x\in X: \|x\|<R\}$. This doesn't have a direct analogue in a general topological space (we want, at least, a metric).